# What is "Burn Jita", and how will it destroy the economy?

Tags: eve-online

In a recent [Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/5905691/eve-oline-producers-declare-players-attempt-to-destroy-games-economy-absolutely-brilliant) article, they described an impending (or current) player-driven plan to "destroy the game's economy" in Eve Online.

The plan is called "Burn Jita", and apparently involves a concerted assault on a trading hub.

However, I am not familiar with Eve Online except in the most general of terms.

Could someone explain what "Burn Jita" is, and  how it would cripple Eve's economy if successful?

Edit:  What are the in-game consequences they alluded to (in reference to the "bookmark escaping agro bug" which was recently fixed)?

Comment: Man I love EVE for exactly this reason.  As for the why of Lander's comments, I think that's covered pretty well by the article, and isn't really on-topic.

Comment: What I read was that there was a bug to avoid the consequences that was fixed, but not what the consequences are, or how it will cripple the economy. As for not on topic, it seems like a question of strategy and game mechanics. I'm not sure I understand how that isn't on topic.

Comment: Why John Lander personally enjoys this idea isn't a question of strategy or mechanics, and he explained why in the interview.

Comment: @MatthewRead Actually, the design philosophy and approach to moderation taken by the developers is relevant to strategy and gameplay as it affects and determines how a game can be played, especially in the case of an MMO - in this case, specifically why is this sort of thing allowed and will similar things be allowed makes this relevant to present and future gameplay of EVE. You are correct though - it says why in the interview.

Comment: Perhaps it seems a lot more obvious if youre familiar with the gameplay. All I got from the article is that there's a massive attack in progress, and the players participating will receive some undefined penalty.

Comment: The article clearly says, "Lead game designer Kristoffer Touborg agreed, explaining that **player-driven events are the core of the game, and the designers are obligated** —once any bugs or exploits are fixed— **not to interfere.**"

Comment: **No. If that were what I was saying, that would be the *answer* that I wrote below - It's not by the way**. I was pointing out what both I and Matthew Read read as the explanation *in the article* for why the designer said it was "brilliant" since you said that you didn't get that from the article. **To say something *is brilliant* is an exclamatory statement (the guy's British) like "it's great", but not necessarily saying anything about the intelligence of the idea.** He was saying that it would be entertaining (to him personally if nobody else) - that's why he said, "it's brilliant".

Comment: @skovacs1 my apologies. I misread your comments and thought you were saying that my overall question was answered in the linked article, and not just the "brilliant" comment. I was under the impression that the players involved were doing something particularly clever, and did not realize the gentleman in question was using it in the british style. I have removed that part from the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EVE uses an [open economy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_economy) based around [supply and demand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_and_demand).

The effects are a bit less predictable, but the general idea is outlined in [this thread](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=88635).

**The idea of Burn Jita is to kill everyone and everything in what is currently the largest trading hub in the game, Jita.** By doing this, killing everyone bringing in supply, shortages will be created, driving up demand and therefore the price. By destroying the their ships, they'll also be costing them currency to replace them and the cost of the cargo lost and inflating the cost of building ships to some degree. However, because of insurance, the victims will actually be getting a flood of money back.

**It won't "destroy" the economy.** It will shuffle it a bit. Jita will become a less hospitable place for trade for a while and traders will go elsewhere. Resources will be a bit more scarce. By forcing trade to go elsewhere, the wealth should become slightly more distributed. Depending *how* concentrated the market in EVE is, the amount of wealth distributed could be a lot or not very much.

The reason the developers support this is because **it is part of their design philosophy to let the game play out as the players interact with it and to interfere as little as possible** - it even says so in the article. The developers might look at it as acceptable/good because it's all good fun and it won't really "destroy" anything - it is a game after all.

Comment: I have a felling that will destroy some monitors and keyboards with the players rage. But ok =)

Comment: Actually, the players have a pretty laid back attitude. Since the goons are essentially zerg rushing, they are easy targets for players wishing to take advantage of this opportunity to improve their killscores and loot things. Also, since this was announced well in advance, the ones who stand to lose the most are likely just staying out of Jita and thus distributing the wealth to other markets.

Comment: Thins like this are why I love EVE.  EVE is more of a PVP game than any other MMO out there in the fact that events that transpire in game are very much player driven.  That said, combine the Burn Jita op with the recent "nerf" to mineral supplies and Goonswarm's new OTEC cartel, and ship prices for anybody not in a large null alliance will likely be more expensive in the near future.  In addition, the recent nerf of income to empire PVE experiences will come into play.  Essentially, we are likely to see a minor recession in the EVE economy for the near future.