# What was the result of Burn Jita?

Tags: eve-online

Related to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64307/what-is-burn-jita-and-how-will-it-destroy-the-economy), was there any final assessment done regarding the Burn Jita campaign? Did the originators of the attack achieve their goal?

Comment: some analysis here: http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2012-05-02-ccp-analyses-eve-online-burn-jita-event but I don't really know what the actual impacts after that one day have been

Answer (score 4):

Here is CCP Explorer's blog on the event, including lots of data and comments by Goonswarm. [Observing The "Burn Jita" Player Event](http://community.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&nbid=28640).

I think the outcome is a bit subjective because the participants naturally want to admit that their efforts were effective, but I have seen a number of other players talk about how it really didn't do much beyond temporarily disrupting Jita and giving people something to do.

Edit: Another link, including some market data. [Jita Done, Hulkageddon is ON!](http://www.evenews24.com/2012/04/30/jita-done-hulkageddon-is-on/)

Comment: i was more wondering economically, e.g mineral and ship price growth to indicate people needing to build up fleets again or long term over all price changes out of jita.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I have not been in game for a bit and missed the event, so I was unable to monitor the market prices. But from what I know about the market and what I have heard (or not heard) from players after the event, it was probably similar to the ice war.  It caused a temporary fluctuation in the market with items associated with those used or lost in the event, and then the market evened out again.  From what I understand, they really didn't kill as many trade ships as hoped, and they certainly lost more combat ships in the process.  But those are disposable for Goons anyway.

Comment: cool, thought that might have been the case. i was hoping enough hulks got destoryed that there would be some lasting effect but its wass always unlikely.

Comment: Well, I believe Hulkageddon began just after Burn Jita, so I am sure there were some Hulks destroyed, but I do not have much info on that.  Oh, I linked another article on Burn Jita that includes some market data in my top post.

Comment: that link was just what i was looking for. thanks heaps, hopefully @fbrereto is around to select it.